# how do i cut a model with selected mesh

Tags: extrude

i am new to blender and i got into it because i didn't have any modeling software that could do what i needed.
In the picture you see a car model the windows on the side need to go but how do i get rid of the "window frames"? i thought i could maybe select the edge of one (picture 2) and extrude it but i doesn't seem like i can cut with the extrude option.

I appreciate the help
Tibo

[image]
[image]

Comment: In Edit Mode select the vertices and then press "X" and select Vertices from the drop down menu. *Don't select the ones where the window frame meets the car.

Comment: You could also try dissolving them instead of deleting them. It might still be workable.

Comment: thanks for your responses but it not really the solution i was looking for if i do it this way it will probably take an hour for me to select all of the vertices on the window frames because there are a lot of dots in some areas.